# Import android.R by default

Tags: android, import, android-resources

Everytime i add a new activity or a new fragment, it gives me the import of android.R by default, instead of the R file from my own application

is there a way to fix that ?

EDIT:

exisiting state:  i create new Activity file, it adds import android.R at the top of the file
desired state : i create new Activity file, it adds import com.mypackage.myapp.R at the top of the file without my needing to delete android.R file and do reimport

Note *: the package is built, com.mypackage.myapp.R does exist in the bin folder

Comment: Please build your project, you will see R.java in bin folder

Comment: I have the R.java in the bin folder, the project builds just fine, the problem is whenever i create a new file, the import android.R is added by default, i don't want that, i want com.mypackage.myapp.R added by default

Answer (score 0):

Your apps R.java must not be generated. Please review your code and clean all your projects (libraries included). And if necessary restart eclipse

Comment: My R file is generated, if i delete android.R import and write my own import, everything works just fine, but WHEN i create a new file,i WANT eclipse not to write android.R as part of my imports

Answer (score 0):

simply delete that import and  then import ur android.R not manually browse it.

Comment: how do i make it so i dont need to do that for every file

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml files there may be some errors and then delete android.R and then clean your project.